# How to avoid data loss inside of a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

I have this strange problem where I loose data in a simple for loop.

Basically I have an interval, that I have to cut in smaller intervals finishing by a mark (here 5.0). The whole result is saved into an array of lists.

I use the switch index (which are the indexes of the number 5 that we can get easily with find comamnds for example) and hte number of blocks (smaller intervals at the end).

My algorithm works well because i print after each loop the smaller interval i extracted. however when passing to the next loop the previous interval gets put to an empty list. Why is this happening? At the end I have a useless array of empty lists.

I added WriteLine statements to show you the problem. Before one pass of a loop finishes i get my interval like i want to, but when passing to the next one, somehow the variable gets emptied

```
    var wholeList = new List<double> { 1.2, 2.5, 5.0, 2.2, 3.4, 5.0, 1.2, 2.5, 5.0, 2.2, 3.4, 5.0, 1.2, 2.5, 5.0, 2.2, 3.4, 5.0 };
    int[] switchIndex = { 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17};
    int number0 = 6;

    var result0 = DivideInterval(wholeList, number0, switchIndex);
```

calling the function

```
    List<double>[] DivideInterval(List<double> myList, int numberOfBlocks, int[] switchingPoint)
    {
        List<double>[] finalArray = new List<double>[numberOfBlocks];
        var temporaryList = new List<double> { };


        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < switchingPoint.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int k = j; k <= switchingPoint[i]; k++)
                temporaryList.Add(myList[k]);

            finalArray[i] = temporaryList;

            Console.WriteLine("---");
            foreach (var item in finalArray[i])
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            temporaryList.Clear();
            j = switchingPoint[i] + 1;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("--final result");
        for (int item = 0; item < finalArray.Length; item++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("length is: " + finalArray[item].Count());
            for (int number = 0; number < finalArray[item].Count(); number++)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--final result");


        return finalArray;

    }
```

Comment: `List<double>[]` - I've never seen that in real life code...

Comment: because the smaller intervals need to be dynamic; they don't have a constant size. they can be big or small. the example is only simple to show the problem. would a list of lists be a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one list, which is

```
var temporaryList = new List<double> { };
```

Note that a list is a reference type.

When you assign it into an array

```
finalArray[i] = temporaryList;
```

and clear it afterwards,

```
temporaryList.Clear();
```

"both" of the lists are cleared: the one in the array and `temporaryList` - because it's actually only one instance (one object).

Instead of

```
temporaryList.Clear();
```

you need to create a new object:

```
temporaryList = new List<double> { };
```

Comment: thank you very much. I kept wondering whether the loop was wrong. I was looking at the problem in the wrong place

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
finalArray[i] = new List<double>();
finalArray[i].AddRange(temporaryList);
```

Instead of this,

```
finalArray[i] = temporaryList;
```